# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') console.log(data) isnt returning user information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

So basically I'm making a login function in React and I've made users using api I've stored the users in my MongoDB database and I'm getting no coding errors in my terminal I now have tried to login to one of the accounts and check the console on my browser and I keep getting back the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data').`

Its saying that my `console.log(data)` isn't reading any properties and I'd appreciate some help on how i can fix this I'll paste down the code below to show what I've done

I need the `console.log(data)` to show the user which I log into information once I've logged in that should appear in the console but the error which I've trying to resolve isn't allowing it

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import './Login.css'


export const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json"
                },
            };

            setLoading(true)
            const { data } = await axios.post(
                "/api/users/login",
                {
                    email,
                    password,
                },
                config
            );


           //Here is the console.log which isnt returning the users info in my console
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response.data);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: "*Its saying that my console.log(data) isn't reading any properties*" no, it's saying it cannot read `data` of `undefined`. Therefore, the problem is when the code tries to read `data` of something that turns out to be `undefined`, not when it tries to use `data`. That would be `const { data } = await axios.post()` which means that the result of `await axios.post()` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, without async/ await.

```
axios.post("api/users/login", { email, password, },config)
  .then(res=>res.data)
  .then(data=> {
    console.log(data);
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
    setLoading(false);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    setError(error)
  })
```

Comment: I just tried and implemented what you posted and im still getting this error in my console POST http://localhost:8000/api/users/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Use absolute URL instead of `api/users/login` because relative URL assumes the API is served in current baseURL & port (localhost:8000) which is not. Your React code runs in this port and not used by API server. `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is because there is connection error to the API URL which you are trying to post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,
in my project I was using axios in an async function with await command as below
(bmUserApi is an api library which I coded myself over axios )

```
onLogin = async(formValues) => {

    this.setState({loading:true, error: ""});    

    try {

        var ls_response = await bmUserApi.login(formValues);

        this.setState({loading: false});

        const lv_token = ls_response.headers['x-auth-token'];
        Redux_Set_User(lv_token, this.props.redux_dispatch, this.props.history);
```

when I was checking the error position on Google Chrome in "Call Stack" part, I've seen that my api library was trying add to authentication token to the api call header, by reading from localStorage of the browser.

I was doing it by using axios interceptors as below :

```
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use( 
    async function(config) {

        config.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        // token :

        var ls_user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));        

        const authToken = ls_user.token;

        if (authToken) 
            config.headers['x-auth-token'] = authToken;

        return config;
    },

    error => { Promise.reject(error) }
)
```

But this is login call .. so off course there is no stored data and token on the browser yet.  So the "ls_user" variable in the above code was null .. this was causing the error.  I just added control before that.

I hope this can be useful to your case.